# preg_replace / strip only two uppercase letters when together

Tags: php, preg-replace, strip

I have a unique thing here when in a sentence I have two uppercase letters together. Like this:

The AA batteries.
The CA power.
The WV chronicles.

etc.

How do you I strip just those uppercase letters? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here ya go

```
preg_match_all("/\b([A-Z]{2})\b/",$string,$matches);
/*
--matches
[0] => The AA batteries. The CA power. The WV chronicles.
[1] => AA
[2] => CA
[3] => WV

*/
```

https://regex101.com/r/rT3jK7/1

**EDIT** - Edited to use preg_match_all instead of preg_match